# how could i change this java script or copy it to have two on click function for two buttons and images

Tags: javascript, html, css

html:

```
<div class="vaultcontainer">
  <img src="img/vault.svg" alt="" id="image">

</div>

<button id="image-button">click </button>
<button id="image-button2">click </button>
```

js:

```
const button = document.getElementById('image-button');
const image = document.getElementById('image');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  changeImage();
});

function changeImage() {
  image.src = 'img/vault2.svg';
}
```

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76247512/edit) your post and include your problem in post, don't only put your question on title and what do you want in 2nd button onclick ?

Comment: If you want to add another event, then just add another button.addEventListener or just extend the Function. And for the 2. Button, you have to search for the 2. ID and add the every EventListener

Answer (score 1):

Use a class:

```html
<button class="js-changeImage">click </button>
<button class="js-changeImage">click </button>
```

then, in JS use `querySelectorAll()` and `.forEach()` on the returned NodeList:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('js-changeImage');

buttons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', changeImage));
```

If you need to specify different images for your buttons — use the [data-* attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes):

```html
<img src="img/vault.svg" alt="" id="image">

<button data-image="img/cat.svg">click </button>
<button data-image="img/dog.svg">click </button>
```

```js
const image = document.querySelector('#image');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-image]');

buttons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  changeImage(btn.dataset.image);
});

function changeImage(src) {
  image.src = src;
}
```

Comment: how would i specify different images for the buttons